# Clipboard button in Paste Context menu

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

Some apps on my phone (s4) have a "paste|clipboard" context menu when long pressing on a edit text, while others have a menu with just "paste".  How do you control which menu is used in your app?

Example of how I want the menu to look:
[Screenshot with clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZjgQ.png)

Example without clipboard button:
[Screenshot without clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAp0a.png)

EDIT: 
So I think it is my Samsung S4's keyboard that is giving this funtionality, and for some reason my app is overriding the Samsung custom Paste menu.  Does anyone know how to allow this menu in my app?

Comment: Can you show screenshots of the difference in your question? It may be that some apps have custom menus, whilst others use the built-in Android menu.